# Pytesseract issue detecting dot

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I do have the following photo:

[image]

I'm trying to extract the text from it but am facing an issue to detect the `dot` within email!

```
In [1]: import cv2

In [2]: import pytesseract

In [3]: img = cv2.imread("images/10008.png")

In [4]: text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img,config='--psm 6')

In [5]: text
Out[5]: 'City: CALGARY\n\nProvince: AB\n\nCountry: CANADA\n\nCompany Name: Bonnyville Immigration Services Inc.\nEmail: sujit saha@live.com\n\nPhone Number: 403-805-0007\n'

In [6]:
```

But i tried that online [site](https://ocr.space/) and it's been able to detect the dot easily if i selected option --> `Use OCR Engine5 (Especially strong with text on complex backgrounds/low contrast)`

Is there a way where i can replicate the same within `pytesseract`

Comment: The image seems crucial for a [mre]. If that image contains private data that needs to be removed, please: 1) Replace the image with another that provides a [mre]. 2) Raise a mod flag to redact that image from the revision history. Simply editing directly still leaves the data on [so], only moderators and staff can redact the history so that the data is no longer there

Comment: I tend to agree that the image is core to this particular question as you were having trouble identifying the dot in the email in _this specific image_. If you can create another image that demonstrates the same issue, but without the sensitive data, I'd be happy to replace the current image with the new one and remove all traces from the revision history.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to successfully filter this image by adding some preprocessing and setting lang="eng" parameter to tesseract.

- convert to grayscale
- resize the image to be wider
- filter it through a sharpening kernel

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils
import pytesseract
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread("data.png", 0)
original = img.copy()

img = imutils.resize(img, width=800)

kernel = np.array([[0,-1,0],
                   [-1,5,-1],
                   [0,-1,0]])

img = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, kernel)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img)
plt.axis("off")

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang="eng", config="--psm 6")
```

output = `'City: CALGARY\n\nProvince: AB\n\nCountry: CANADA\n\nCompany Name: Bonnyville Immigration Services Inc.\nEmail: sujit.zaha@live.com\n\nPhone Number:  403-805-0007'`

[image: Processed Image]